# Authenticate a device/user based on a single URL request

Tags: java, security, authentication, device, owasp

We currently have a J2EE system implementing most of the OWASP top 10 security measures, the application at the moment allows users to log on with a user/password combination which is stored in the database.

I have a java filter mapped to `/*` to check for session and session attribute presence to determine a user's logged in state.

Ok, finally here is the problem: We are integrating with a company that manufactures devices to send a URL request via GPRS when a certain event occurs, this URL is a link to our system.

I would (without compromising security) like to authenticate this 'device', it is not possible to send the device any information, so a single request needs to be authenticated an no one should be able to 'replay' that URL

I do not know if this is possible without some sort of mutual authentication. I thought about a white-list of IP addresses to check against, but the networks constantly change IP's and the device is still 'unidentified'. Please advise any ideas?

PS: my temporary solution was to add a exception to my filter, but this is not long term and totally insecure. (SSL is also not an option)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could let the device sign the request (*including* a unique request identifier) with a private key. Then, the server can check if the signature is valid and only accept/answer the request when it is.

The request ID can be used to ensure that such requests are not replayed. Using a simple counter for the request ID would mean that it's very easy to check if a given identifier has already been used (i.e. if the request is being replayed).

Comment: +1 - Some sort of digital signature might help. Beware that it may be possible to reverse engineer the private key if it is embedded in the device. This is especially bad if all devices share the same key.

Comment: Thank you, ok i know now that at in the worst case the device can receive if we really need to but it is not optimal. I do not totally understand your answer, i understand the requestID/counter but not how to sign it. it led me into a google session where the only thing i could find was oAuth. Could you please explain more Joachim?

Comment: @epoch digital signature is made using the private key stored on device (and it is desirable that it's non-extractable). The session ID can be an ever-incrementing number and it will be signed. The server will keep the last used session ID for given device (based on device's identifier and signature).

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that whatever authentication info the device includes can become available to the third-party if he gets the device.

So the main questions are (a) what exactly you want to authenticate (should it be the device itself or it's owner or device's location or ... ) and (b) what features the device can support -- what kind of device it is and what it can do in operational aspects.

If the device can embed a smartcard or cryptotoken which are designed to hold private keys and counteract extraction attempts then digital signature will work great.

If the device can have protected memory but can not perform cryptographic operations (and can't embed a smartcard), then I can think of the list of precomputed one-time passwords, unique for each device. The server would have a copy of the global list, and remove the password from the list once the list is used.

Comment: Hi Eugene, I want to make it as generic as possible, so for instance if i add the functionality for the device it would be cool if lets say a mobile phone could use the same use-case (guest login of protected page). So programming a very device specific solution is also not the best for me

Comment: @epoch Mobile phones have both protected storage (in most cases) and capability to perform cryptographic operations so they are not a problem. It's specific devices that can be a problem. So I think you will end up with several solutions, one for each class of capabilities.